# Compass and Sass are dead?

Tags: css, sass, compass

I am going through the [code school](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/assembling-sass) course "Sass Foundation". I am on a level where the professor tells about the compass framework.
When I installed it I realized that the code which it generates does not include the -ms- and -o-.

That is why I would like to ask professionals for some tips, and information which I cannot find here on Stack and on the Internet.

1. Is the Compass dead now? If yes what should I use instead of it? 
   (to be sure that it will add -ms-, -o- etc.)
2. Is the Sass dead now?
3. I did some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597950/sass-and-compass) and the people say that I should not use the    .sass but .scss, but on the other hand, if I use the .scss I won't be able to use the indented syntax. Should I avoid the indented syntax? If yes please specify why.

Comment: It could be that you just need to set a flag to get it to output the -ms- and -o-. Note i have no experience whatsoever in Compass.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since none of the answers are 100% accurate, I will provide my own answer.

1. Is Compass dead? ***Yes, apparently.*** According to their [GitHub page](https://github.com/Compass/compass):

   > Compass is no longer actively maintained.

   Compass seems to be dying because it is written in Ruby and there are much faster Sass transpilers written in C/C++, mainly [LibSass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass).

   What should you use now? Based on [this GitHub issue conversation](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/82), I would recommend switching to [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) for a base set of utility mixins.
2. Is Sass dead now? **No, absolutely not.** Modern Sass transpilers, including LibSass, fully support the Sass specification and work great.
3. Should you avoid the Sass syntax? **No.** In my opinion, the Sass syntax is cleaner, easier to read, and is definitely easier to type.

   You can mix Sass and SCSS syntax. So you can import Bourbon SCSS syntax into your Sass syntax document and use the mixins without issue.

   In conclusion, use the syntax that makes you happier.

Comment: _"Compass seems to be dying because it is written in Ruby ... I would recommend switching to Bourbon"_ -- but [that's also Ruby](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon#installation)...

Comment: True. Bourbon has a lot of Ruby code, but my understanding is that it generates pure Sass mixins, so you can run a C++ based Sass transpiler like libsass. Bourbon, unfortunately, is also disappearing and being replaced with node-based solutions like Autoprefixer.

Comment: And if you use something like create-react-app, it will just support Sass and SCSS and use Autoprefixer by default.

Comment: libsass is not maintained anymore!!!

Comment: True. This post is old. LibSass has been replaced with node-sass.

Answer (score 5):

Compass is not, dead - it did what it did well - but it's now been replaced in most peoples' work flows. People started using CodeKit shortly after that- and now they generally use task runners and build tools like, grunt, gulp, brunch, broccoli etc.

What you want is pre-processing and something that has autoprefixer. This could be any of the things mentioned above and can usually be installed and configured with a collection of npm  modules. It all depends on the project you're working on. I'd say that gulp is the most popular right now. (I use Ember, so Ember CLI does that for me)

.sass is just another syntax (the original one, I believe). Most developers use .scss and I'd encourage you to stick with that syntax because it's more like CSS and when sharing projects people will thank you. (although I prefer stylus)

#### EDIT

Afterthoughts... I'd say that "Sass Foundation" is what is *dead*. That course is going to cause you more trouble then help you. Just write scss and learn new bits as you need them. It's just CSS with some helpful features like variables and nesting.

Comment: "Compass is not, dead" was supposed to be "Compass is now dead", right?

Comment: I mean, I was just trying to decrypt that quoted text of yours. Never mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I'm understanding what you're asking, yes, I would transition to SCSS instead of using SASS. Why? Generally speaking, **SASS** combines both *Sass* and *SCSS*. Sass itself is an older syntax that primarily deals with indentation (instead of brackets, etc.) and doesn't present any real addition to CSS. On the other hand, SCSS is meant to extend CSS3 by providing additional functionality such as variables, nesting, and others. The other bonus is that technically speaking, every valid CSS3 stylesheet is also a valid SCSS stylesheet.

So to conclude, I would definitely consider making the change to SCSS as you will find this is the standard among a lot of frameworks and tools used in the industry, plus it is a newer syntax in comparison to Sass and provides a good deal more functionality to make your life that much easier as a developer.

If you want to find out more information, just take a look at their website: http://sass-lang.com/

So to answer your questions specifically:

1. No, it is not dead, it has just been updated to follow industry standards. There are many alternatives available. For example, a popular one is Gulp.
2. Sass isn't dead either, however most developers have moved to SCSS instead.
3. I would go with SCSS, due to what I have described above.

Comment: The information here isn't right. The SASS indented syntax is functionally equivalent to SCSS syntax - there's no difference in features you can use.

Comment: This answer is totally incorrect. As the above comment mentioned, Sass (i.e. the indented syntax) and SCSS are just 2 different syntax flavors of Sass (the CSS preprocessor) and they have the same capabilities and functionalities.

Comment: Sass syntax is pretty much capable of those things you mention like variables and nesting.